Targeting attributes of the currently selected tab
I currently have a ttk.Notebook, tabControl, that is initialized with a singular tab, first tab. That tab comes with a tk.Text, txt.
        tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self.root)    
        
        first_tab = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
        tabControl.add(first_tab, text='Tab 1')     
        
        txt = tk.Text(first_tab, wrap="word", width=30, height=10)
        txt.pack(padx=5,pady=5,fill="both",expand=True)

        tabControl.pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="right")

The user is offered the option of creating a new tab via a button. A user-created tab is designed as so:
def add_new_tab(notebook):
        new_tab_frame = ttk.Frame(notebook)

        txt = tk.Text(new_tab_frame, wrap="word", width=40, height=10)
        txt.pack(padx=10,pady=10,fill="both",expand=True)
        
        notebook.add(new_tab_frame, text="New Tab")

How would I go about accessing the tk.Text of the currently selected tab?
I ask for the reason of adding text to the text widget of the currently selected tab. User is currently only allowed to transcribe an audio file to the first_tab, but I would like a way to let the user transcribe to one tab, switch to another tab and transcribe again.
I am aware of the .select() method to find a tab, but I wasn't able to target the tk.Text of that tab. Any help would be appreciated.

Suggest to create a custom Frame class with a Text widget inside and it is more easier to access the Text widget:
class TextFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.txt = tk.Text(self, wrap="word")
        self.txt.pack(padx=5, pady=5, fill="both", expand=True)

Then add instance of this custom frame to the notebook:
def add_new_tab(notebook):
    new_tab_frame = TextFrame(notebook)
    notebook.add(new_tab_frame, text="New Tab")

As you said, you can use Notebook.select() to get the name of the frame of the selected tab and you can use .nametowidget() to get the reference to the frame.  Then you can access the Text widget inside that frame:
frame = tabControl.nametowidget(tabControl.select())
# use frame.txt to access the internal Text widget
frame.txt.insert("end", "Hello\n")


Or simply add a Text widget instead of Frame to the notebook directly.

Wow, I would have never thought to make a custom class. That did make it a lot easier, exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!
